How to let root use sudoedit as if it was a user?
I'm writing a wrapper for myself around vim that detects when the user's trying to edit a file that doesn't belong to them, and suggests sudoedit or visudo instead. I want to use sudoedit rather than sudo vim, as I believe it's best practice.
The problem is that when the user runs sudo vim FILENAME, I can't make sudoedit behave like it was called by the user. By that, I mean the temporary copy of the edited file should belong to the caller and not root, and I assume there's also more subtle security policy differences.
Here's what that part of my script looks like - assume it is called instead of vim:
#!/bin/bash

# check if script ran by root
if [[ $# -eq 1 ]]  && [ -f $1 ] && [ "$EUID" -eq 0 ]
then
    # warning: root has to be a sudoers to be able to run the sudo command
    if [[ $(realpath $1) == "/etc/sudoers" ]]
    then
        echo "Using visudo to edit $1"
        # using a heredoc makes vim throw:
        # Vim: Warning: Input is not from a terminal
        # and vim takes a full 2 seconds to open
        sudo -i -u USERNAME bash << EOF
# two password prompts for USERNAME are displayed
# user's cached auth is not used
sudo visudo
EOF
        exit 0
    else
        echo "Using sudoedit to edit $1"
        # the temp file still belongs to root:
        # the -u argument does not do anything
        sudo -u USERNAME -e "$1"
        exit 0
    fi
fi
# default behavior
vim "$@"


Using a heredoc to run sudoedit as the user seems to have the correct effect security-policy wise, but I don't like the behavior from a user perspective
running sudo -e as the user does not actually do it as the user

Another option I thought about is to create a sudo function in my .bashrc so that when calling sudo vim, the correct command is called by the correct user - see the last suggestion in this answer. However, I'm not sure wrapping sudo / changing its behavior is a good idea.
Does anyone have advice on how to do what I want, or if I should even do it?

(1) "user's cached auth is not used" – It's probably per tty (man 5 sudoers, see timestamp_type) and the sudo vim FILENAME has probably provided a separate tty (man 5 sudoers, use_pty). (2) In a heredoc stdin is from the heredoc, hence "… not from a terminal" printed by the vim run by sudo visudo. </dev/tty sudo visudo >/dev/tty 2>&1 may be helpful. More so, if you manage to redirect to the original tty. (3) "the temp file still belongs to root" – In sudo -e the editor runs as the invoking user; try something like sudo -u USERNAME sudo -e "$1" (note: I have not tested).

sudo -u USERNAME sudo -e "$1" seems like it solves my problem - I'm getting two password prompts, but that's probably just a matter of configuring sudo permissions for root.
Should I answer my own question, or would you like to format that into an answer yourself ?

"probably just a matter of configuring sudo permissions for root" – I doubt it. I think that's because of tty being different, see (1) in my previous comment. I did not answer the question because the phrase "I don't like the behavior from a user perspective" is vague. E.g. I thought that "two password prompts" was a part of the problem. I cannot address the "if I should even do it" part. Frankly I do not feel I can write a good, comprehensive answer, so I'm not going to. Still I wanted to help somehow. I wrote what I know, so you (or anyone else) can advance in your (their) research.
